# Unit Test Adapter Threw exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I am facing exception as shown below when running a coded ui test method.

It terminates before entering in test method body and return exception

```
Message: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFrmework...
```

As shown below in image libraries are already added.

[image]

I am using following version in entire project

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework //version 14.0.0.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework //Version 10.1.0.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common //Version 14.0.0.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension //Version 14.0.0.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting //Version 14.0.0.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Judging by version, you have `Specific Version` set to true in the reference and something wants the oolder assembly?

Comment: I have just updated post and mentioned versions i am using.

Comment: does any of the project references have `SpecificVersion` set to true?

Comment: Yes, all references mentioned in post have specific version set to true.

Comment: I changed specific version to false and got following errorThe type 'CodedUITestAttribute' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Answer (score 2):

I just checked my app.config and found following lines were added there.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.1.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I do not know how it happen but when i removed this, everything started working fine.

Comment: You can and should set this answer as the correct one - you'll get a bit of rep and it'll show up at the top for anyone who stumbles here